# Failure-Installation of Jess rule engine

Tags: java, eclipse, jess

I have installed eclipse oxygen and then installed Jess rules engine 7.1.0 on windows 10.  The Jess logo appears on the main "About Eclipse SDK" window but i can only see one Jess-related plugins in the list. Documentation state that they should be 3 or 4. if i proceed and create a file such as hello.clp, it does not open in the jess editor. S

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Jess plugins work with Eclipse Juno and earlier.